# How to understand the jmeter result whether which is correct or not?

Tags: load, jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

I Couldn't understand the exact result from the jmeter whether which is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

The View Results Tree is the default Listener added to every project. If you look in there, you will see all the steps that ran during your test. If you see a green checkmark, the step passed, otherwise, you will see a red x indicating a failure.

When you click on a step in the View Tree Results, there are 3 tabs you can view.
1) Sampler result - indicates time, size, response code and response message
2) Request - shows what was sent
3) Response data - shows what was returned

You can add Assertions to each step to specify the criteria for pass/fail. I use Response Assertion's on just about every step to prevent false positives.

Comment: Thank you, but still i could see all these things and that has given already in some portals, but thing is the given result in jmeter is correct or not, am getting a green mark for 30 users login 1 loop in 1 rampup time. but if i go ahead with 31 users it shows an error 25% in the summary report, so is my way of working in jmeter is correct and whether the result is right or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to design your tests in correct manner. If you are running tests for 1 iteration that itself needs to be rectified. You need enough number of samples so run the test with some more iterations or run it for longer duration.

In order to find the correctness of the response add response assertions but if you are sure about the correctness of response you are getting next thing is to understand the actual test results.

If you are seeing high error percentage with increasing load which means your system is not able to handle that much load concurrently. I would suggest you try following :

1. Run test with 1 user. Take note of throughput and response time.
2. Run test with 10 users. Take note of throughput and response time.
3. Run test with 30 users and Take note of throughput and response time and as you mentioned earlier run test with 35/40 users and check how the system behaves.

Taking these data points will help you understand the trend in system performance with increasing load. You can also check resource utilization while running these tests. This way you can figure out how much concurrency your system supports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.